# ValueError: 'too many values to unpack' on trying access from Database

Tags: python, database, python-2.x

I'm trying to fetch data from DB and store

But I'm getting an error

```
[pqr] = abc_report.updates[0]['mno'][0]['groups'][0]['params'].iteritems()
```

The data is something like this in the params

```
{u'def': True, u'efg': 17, u'ijk': 127,  u'xyz': True}
```

Comment: `pqr = {u'def': True, u'efg': 17, u'ijk': 127,  u'xyz': True}`   ?

Comment: @Rakesh : No, thats the value of params

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the square brackets around `[pqr]`. The square brackets here make python try and unpack the return from `iteritems()`. The return will be more than one value and you are trying to assign to only one value; python will not let you do this.

Comment: i removed square brackets and checked what is the value of pqr and the answer is this --> <dictionary-itemiterator object at 0x7f90789175d0>

Comment: That's what `iteritems()` returns. You can then loop over it to get each individual value using `for item in pqr:`. If you want more information or a specific outcome you should ask a new question with more details. There's some help for asking questions on stack overflow here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask